# Good open source (free) proxy server for install to create a web based proxy

Tags: web-server, proxy

I am looking for some open source proxy server software that I can install on a machine at home/VPS that when accessed remotely performs as a web based proxy.

A good GUI is a nice to have as I'm not that good at command line stuff. Don't mind the operating system as I could set it up on a virtual machine for it.

My corporate job with their firewall are making it very difficult for me to access some sites I need to do some home business stuff - such as gmail, dropbox, etc. I figured if I can set up a webproxy (either at home or on a VPS somewhere) I could use that. I would use a public one but alas they are very good at blocking those too.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squid + Webmin, and the [webmin squid plugin](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/SquidProxyServer) is probably what you need.

You could also look at [logmein](https://secure.logmein.com) as an alternative (there are several different remote-control-via-browser options around), to just remote access your home machine via a browser (though your IT people should have this locked down).  This would stop you needing to put things on your work PC such as dropbox.

Comment: I also found PHProx which appears to be a simple script I could host on LAMP VM.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for something like Squid, but I don't know of a good GUI for it. Don't take this the wrong way but you should probably do your job at your job and your home business at home.

Comment: It's like my boss is online :-) Thanks for your feedback.